# Host Name binding not working with wildcard (all) IP Address on IIS10

Tags: iis, host-headers

I am trying to configure a site binding on IIS10.

I want to be able to run multiple sites on the same ports and differentiate the sites by their host header.

For some reason IIS does not seem to resolve a host-name binding unless a specific interface is also selected.

I have previously configured sites on IIS 7.5 and 8.5 in a similar manner so I am at a bit of a loss to explain the behaviour I am seeing.

I have set up a new website with only a "hello world" html document to try an isolate my issue.
The site is running on a port that is not used by any other website.

The host-name binding works, only if I also specify an interface.

| Type | Host-name | IP address | Port | Works? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http |  | * | 30080 | **Yes** |
| http | host-troubleshooting.test.internal | * | 30080 | **No** |
| http | host-troubleshooting.test.internal | 10.xxx.xxx.163 | 30080 | **Yes** |

In all cases I accessing the site using the same address and port:
http://host-troubleshooting.test.internal:30080/

When I configure IIS to bind to the host and all IP addresses I get a generic 502 connection refused error

** Does Not Work **
[image]

**Update**

Using netstat it appears that there is nothing listening on the port when I have specified a wildcard ip address in the binding:
[image: netstat report no listener]

When a specific interface is selected; a listener is created
[image: netstat reports listener]

Comment: IIS10 behaves exactly the same way as 7.5 or 8. There is no need to specify the IP address to get host-name resolution working. Something else must be wrong on your server. Anything in the http-logs for the 502s?

Comment: Without accessing this specific machine, it is impossible to troubleshoot further. Likely something on it conflicts with certain site bindings, so it returns 502 instead of IIS. This is quite normal, as Windows HTTP API is open to all applications, not just IIS.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I've a few more things to try; but I think i'm just going to be logging  a ticket with MSFT shortly.  Will updated once if I ever get a satisfactory explination for what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Performing an IIS Reset causes IIS to pickup the host bindings as expected and also shows the port being bound as expected when using netstat.

I don't have a satisfactory explanation as to why IIS is not listening on the binding immediately after creation / updating.